# javascript - changing title appends rather than rewrites

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a news feed script which automatically informs the user when new news items are available, like on twitter. I want to add this alert to the title so used this;

```
var originalTitle = document.title;
document.title = '(' + result + ') ' + originalTitle;
```

Now I don't see the problem but it appends the `result` value before the `originalTitle` which would be fine if it wasn't costantly being updated whenever there's new news.

E.g; If 1 story is added and not another for a long time you get this;

```
(1) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) title
```

E.g 2; If stories keep on getting added you get this;

```
(5) (4) (3) (2) (1) title
```

Not pretty. I want the while title to be rewritten each time and not just have the `result` appended infront each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `originalTitle` is being over-written *each* time with whatever happens to be the title at the moment, which is why you're winding up with `(5) (4) ... title`

Just save the original title in **one** place, with the line of code you already have.

```
var originalTitle = document.title;
```

Call that line in your document.ready handler, and leave it alone.  Then each time you want to update the title, this should do what you want

```
document.title = '(' + result + ') ' + originalTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because you're updating `originalTitle` everytime, thus first it's

```
(1) title
```

then when you call originalTitle again, it's "(1) title", not just title. so just set originalTitle at the top somewhere, and don't update it.